# Error on remote notifications with swift and iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm getting the following error on `var setting...` line only on iOS 7.1:

[image]

No more clues about it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();
    return true
}
```

On iOS 8.1 and 8.2 works fine. Could you point me on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIUserNotificationSettings` is available from ios 8 along with `registerUserNotificationSettings`

You can use `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` for iOS 7 but you will need to detect it on runtime (the OS version) and use the proper method.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this in objective-c is as follows, it may help you.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]){
    // This will execute for iOS 8
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    // This will execute for iOS 7 and prior
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```